# Can I select parts of a street with the Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to be able select/delete/update some parts of the streets on a Google map (as on picture bellow).

This selected parts must be saved on the server and there must be a counter of the selected distance.

Is there a possible solution of this problem with the Google Maps API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Google Maps Javascript API.

The code for encoding:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Encoding methods</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          #right-panel {
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
          }
    
          #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
            font-size: 15px;
          }
    
          #right-panel select {
            width: 100%;
          }
    
          #right-panel i {
            font-size: 12px;
          }
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
          }
          #right-panel {
            width: 46%;
            float: left;
          }
          #encoded-polyline {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="right-panel">
          <div>Encoding:</div>
          <textarea id="encoded-polyline"></textarea>
        </div>
        <script>
              var poly, map;
          // This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
          // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
          // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
    
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 14,
              center: {lat: 34.366, lng: -89.519}
            });
    
            // Add a listener for the click event
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
              addLatLngToPoly(event.latLng, poly);
            });
          }
    
          /**
           * Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
           * Updates the encoding text area with the path's encoded values.
           */
          function addLatLngToPoly(latLng) {
   if(!poly){
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
       strokeColor: '#000000',
       strokeOpacity: 1,
       strokeWeight: 3,
       map: map
     });
   }
            var path = poly.getPath();
            // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
            // and it will automatically appear
   if(path.length==2){
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
       strokeColor: '#000000',
       strokeOpacity: 1,
       strokeWeight: 3,
       map: map
     });
   }
   path = poly.getPath();
   path.push(latLng);
            // Update the text field to display the polyline encodings
            var encodeString = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
            if (encodeString) {
              document.getElementById('encoded-polyline').value = encodeString;
            }
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
      </body>
```

You can save the encoded string in the database.

Similarly you can decode a saved polyline:

```html
 <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Test</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    #map {width:670px;height:600px;}
    </style> 
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.65905179951626, 7.3835928124999555);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            
        var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('}~kvHmzrr@ba\\hnc@jiu@r{Zqx~@hjp@pwEhnc@zhu@zflAbxn@fhjBvqHroaAgcnAp}gAeahAtqGkngAinc@_h|@r{Zad\\y|_D}_y@swg@ysg@}llBpoZqa{@xrw@~eBaaX}{uAero@uqGadY}nr@`dYs_NquNgbjAf{l@|yh@bfc@}nr@z}q@i|i@zgz@r{ZhjFr}gApob@ff}@laIsen@dgYhdPvbIren@'); 
        var decodedLevels = decodeLevels("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
    
        var setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: decodedPath,
            levels: decodedLevels,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            map: map
        });
    }
    
    function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
        var decodedLevels = [];
    
        for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
            var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
            decodedLevels.push(level);
        }
        return decodedLevels;
    }
    </script> 
    </head> 
    <body onload="initialize()"> 
    <div id="map"></div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: It's possible to create many not connected polylines instead of one polyline?

Comment: Updated the code snippet. Now you can add many connected polylines with between 2 points. Textbox will show string for last polyline. Hope it helps!